# How to prevent re-ordering of app icon locations after apps re-enabled on a MDM-enrolled device?

Tags: mobile-device-management

It is possible for a MDM to disable almost all apps on an iOS device by issuing a configuration profile that specifies "no apps" in the Restrictions Payload.  When disabled, apps simply disappear from the device home screen.

My problem is that if I distribute configuration profiles with this restriction and then later distribute new profiles removing the restriction, all of the app icons on the device reappear but not organized as they were before they were disable.

Any ideas on how to prevent or workaround this?

Comment: Seriously don't think there's a workaround, but I do know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kidslox](https://kidslox.com/) have a workaround they call [Icon Fixer](http://iconfixer.com).  I haven't tested this, but came across it a while ago.

> ... Once downloaded, the Icon Fixer ‘app’ will appear as a greyed out icon on your device. It’s basically an app that never fully installs and this frozen state is what keeps the apps in order when using Kidslox.

Comment: I had no idea that could possibly exist, but cool.